# Bitcoin Transaction Scripts

Tags: transactions, blockchain, protocol, api

Could someone explain to me how the bitcoin transaction scripts work?How to build custom scripts?
Also please explain the data structure of transactions as specified by the bitcoin protocol? How to collect unconfirmed transactions to start mining, what is protocol API for writing python scripts to collect transactions, generate blocks, build transactions and other necessary information to build a bitcoin client from scratch?

Comment: [There is no spec for a full bitcoin client that is shorter than the source code for the standard client.](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin)

Comment: I think it would be handy to develop libraries implementing the protocol methods for building transaction scripts as well as generating blocks(mining) and provide a handy interface to the bitcoin protocol just like "requests" and "twisted" libraries.

Answer (score 1):

A client for transactional purposes can have less capabilities than a client that also will perform the tasks needed to support mining.

A lightweight client to review might be [picocoin](https://github.com/jgarzik/picocoin), "a tiny bitcoin library, with lightweight client and utils".

Comment: Nice simple library but what I was asking for is a thorough explanation to the points I mentioned above, anyway I found this post [285-bytes-that-changed-the-world](http://james.lab6.com/2012/01/12/bitcoin-285-bytes-that-changed-the-world/).